# When is the right time to ask about work schedule?

Tags: interviewing

My impression is that asking during the hiring process may hinder my candidacy.

But at the same time, due to extracurricular commitments I need a flexible schedule. I am not talking about anything outrageous. Just starting in the afternoon or working from home a couple of times a week.

Obviously this needs to be hashed out before I join, but when to do it? In the interview? After receipt of an offer?

Comment: If it may hinder your candidacy - would you rather find out sooner or later?

Answer (score 15):

> My impression is that asking during the hiring process may hinder my
>   candidacy.
>
> But at the same time, due to extracurricular commitments I need a
>   flexible schedule.

If you *need* a flexible schedule, then not asking about it during the hiring process would be rather foolish.

Employers who don't offer a flexible schedule are exactly the type you want to cross off your list. Why waste any time with them?

During your interviews, you *must* determine if the employer is a good fit for your needs, just as they must determine if you are a good fit for their position.

Comment: +1 especially for the last line. Always remember that interviews are meant for **both parties** to determine whether there's a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously this needs to be hashed out before I join, but when to do
>   it? In the interview? After receipt of an offer?

Depends how much time you are willing to waste if they end up being unable to accommodate your needs. If you don't want to waste time, do it before scheduling the interview, just after first contact. If you're happy for a little time to be wasted, either bring it up during the interview or wait until you receive an offer. If you wait until you receive an offer, the company is more invested in hiring you and you can then negotiate on their offer and include your needs in those negotiations.

As a side point, I'd keep it strictly on a "need" level and not a "want" level. Most employers say they are flexible, but that's generally not going to be flexible enough for you, so you will be asking for special treatment... That's ok, as long as that's what you really need.

Comment: I don't think the company will react differently at start or at the end of the interview process - they're either willing to accomodate or not.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree. Once a company has gone through the interview process and decided you were the best candidate available, they have a certain level of investment in you that you can use to your advantage in negotiations. By making you an offer, they are telling you that every other candidate available is second best.

Comment: If it's important to a company that you are there the full working day, it doesn't matter that you were top of the list... if it isn't important to a company, it doesn't matter when you tell them. I think you overstate the "investment" organisations have in candidates when they have several suitable candidates available.

Comment: @HorusKol - I think it's somewhere inbetween.  If they like you, they may be willing to be flexible in a way which would have outright disqualified you before they brought you in.  But it only goes so far - better to find a different candidate than hire someone who is incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get at it during the "do you have any questions for me" portion of the interview, just do it indirectly with questions like:

"What is a typical day like in this position?" or

"I would be commuting from 'x' when would be a good time to head in to avoid the traffic?" or

"How is your commute?"

probe a bit.  Other answers might come out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it is proportional to how important it is to you and how unusual the request is. The more important it is to you and the more unusual it is the sooner you should be talking about it with them. If it is truly a make or break criteria you should even consider including it in your resume/cover letter/CV.

Sure you are going to kill some interviews before the process even gets started by doing this but spending a bunch of time interviewing with a company who can't or won't be able to meet your needs is just a waste of time for both of you. It probably will make finding a job a little or a lot harder but that is your choice. Ultimately you may have to decide if finding a good job is more important than your extracurricular commitments.

In some industries working from home or working a flexible schedule are common and not a big deal but in others working from home may be impossible and flexible schedules may be very difficult. Take any customer service job. You need certain amounts of coverage at certain times and you can't let people show up when they like and even planning it ahead means basically making them schedule other people around your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would even put this request into my *cover letter.* Either the company's policies will accommodate it, or they will not.  You really don't want to "be picked to be interviewed" ... strange though that might seem when you are desperate for work ... if your needs can't be accommodated when you are employed there. And they, in turn, don't want to waste *their* time considering a candidate who can't be hired.